# Format external HDD partition that is encrypted, locked and hidden

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, external-hard-drive, hard-drive-recovery

I have this 320GB Stealth HD Bio external HDD from MXI Security. It has two partitions - a private encrypted partition of 304969MB and a public partition of 8.97MB. I forgot the administrator password and the private partition got locked after 10 incorrect attempts. Is there any way to wipe the entire HDD and re-use it as a normal HDD? I don't care about the data in it anymore.

After doing some research, I tried formatting using different tools like GParted, PartitionMagic etc. The problem is that all these tools only detect the public partition. The private partition is hidden and not detected at  all; hence I am unable to do anything to it. The public partition can't be wiped either. I look forward to any help in this regard.

Comment: Remove the hard drive from the MXI enclosure, insert into a generic enclosure, see if you can format both partitions now.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a patched firmware installed that allows resetting it, it is not possible.

That is part of the overall protection of the drive, preventing undesired attempts to erase its content, which in certain cases is worse than making the data visible.